# Something wrong with HTML, body and a div

Tags: html, css

so I keep having this weird problem that I have never seen before ... as we all know, a div is inside a body and we can make body margin 0 and padding 0 to cover the entire page with height and width 100% ... The problem is, when I try to margin a div inside the body THE ENTIRE BODY moves :S .. and to my surprise if I use firebug and hover over the body, its not the entire page. its just slightly bigger than the dive ... here is the code (first part is HTML, second is CSS)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/general-style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css-buttons.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css-colors.css"/>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"> <!-- footer div starts here -->
  </div> <!-- footer div starts here -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#content{
  background: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 100px
  height: 350px
  width:350px
}

#footer{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

#footer-text{
  font-size:xx-small;
  margin-top:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the way it works, margins collapse. What are you trying to do? You could just set the background-color on the HTML tag, or use CSS's top/left properties to position the div.

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

Answer (score 2):

As TJHeuvel already said, this is collapsing margin. There are two solutions to this: set padding on the parent element (`body` in this case) or border. You can read more about it here: http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/

Answer (score 0):

HTMl CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/general-style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css-buttons.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css-colors.css"/>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"> <!-- footer div starts here -->
  </div> <!-- footer div starts here -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html{
}

body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#content{
  background: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 100px
  height: 350px
  width:350px
}

#footer{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

#footer-text{
  font-size:xx-small;
  margin-top:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

TRY THIS